# Rsyncd.secrets file linux permission: should not be read by group and others

Tags: linux, rsync

### In my rsync server /etc/rsyncd.conf file, I have "secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets".

If I change file permission with "chmod 600 /etc/rsyncd.secrets", after I ran rsync command on my client to the server, every thing work fine. 
If it's "chmod 644 /etc/rsyncd.secrets", however, my client end up with 
"@ERROR: auth failed on module www_cn_mad 
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1534) [sender=3.0.9]"
I don't know why 644 permission matters..

Answer (score 4):

In Rsync, there is a parameter called "strict modes" that can be set in /etc/rsyncd.conf.  By default, this parameter is true even if it is not set in the configuration file.  "strict modes" runs a check on the secrets file to determine if it is readable by any other user id than what rsync is running under.  This is good to have as a check that your secrets file is not visible to the world.  If you want to use 644 permissions on the secrets file, you'll need to add the line

stricts modes = no

to your rsyncd configuration file to disable the check.  I'd recommend you set 600 permissions and leave strict modes enabled for security.

-TW